# Ignoring resource path from already generated jar in Maven

Tags: maven, pom.xml

How to exclude resource directory from a already generated jar in Maven? Here is an example:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>car.toyota</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>vehicle-example</groupId>
       <artifactId>vehicle-car</artifactId>
       <version>20.0.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How do I exclude the resource directory of vehicle-car?

Answer (score 1):

You don't :)

If you own the module - you can split it into multiple modules, and include only the ones you really need.

If you don't own it - you could either repackage it yourself or use a plugin, see answer here: [How to repackage to jar after assembly goal using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398723/how-to-repackage-to-jar-after-assembly-goal-using-maven)